# Why is e.target.getAttribute('name') always producing null?

Tags: polymer

Not in the [tutorial](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-1.html), but in the [github repo](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-tutorial/blob/master/step-1/index.html), there is the following line:

```
console.log("tab change: " + e.target.getAttribute('name') +" selected = " + e.detail.isSelected);
```

And e.target.getAttribute('name') is always producing null.

Q: Why?

Comment: Element on which the event runs doesn't have a `name` attribute?

Comment: @Phillip could you please add the relevant part of the GitHub code to your question (only the `<core-header-panel>` element and the JavaScript) for future reference. The GitHub repo may change, making it unclear what was asked and answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`e.target` referes to the `<paper-tabs>` element, which indeed has no attribute `name`. The target is the element that sent the event.

The selected/deselected `<paper-tab>` element can be found in `e.detail.item`, so `console.log(e.detail.item.getAttribute("name"))` prints the correct *name* attribute.

(If one uses [declarative event mapping](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping), the event detail data is passed in the event handler as a shortcut in a second parameter.)